# How to remove element and replace with space instead of display:none in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

**Context:**

Hi i am new to vuetify and i am trying to solve below problem using v-spacer/vuetify classes without using any custom css.

Below is the screenshot of what i am trying to acheive.

[image]

**Problem:**

I have a v-show  on icon button which basically removes the button component i.e applies display none, when i click on card the gap/gutter space which was created by button component is lost.

How do i maintain gap/gutter space using vuetify, any suggestions would be helpful.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
        hide1:false,
      hide2:true
     }
    
   }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
         <v-layout row wrap>
                  <v-flex xs12>
                          <v-layout style="background:#eb596e" fill-height>
                                  <v-flex shrink v-for="i in 5">
                                   <v-layout style="background:#51c2d5">
                                       <v-flex> <v-card @click="hide1=!hide1" color="#ffe227" style="height:200px;width:200px"/> {{hide1}}</v-flex>
                                     <v-flex>          
                <v-tooltip top>
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-btn
                      fab
                      v-on="on"
                      style="width:22px;height:20px"
                           v-show="!hide1"
                    >
                      <v-icon color="primary" size="17px">
                        more_vert
                      </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                  </template>
                  <span>
                  {{'hello'}}
                  </span>
                </v-tooltip> </v-flex>
                                     </v-layout>
                                </v-flex>
                           </v-layout>
                  </v-flex>
               </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty div with class name `spacer` which has the following style rules :

```
.spacer{
width:38px;
height:100%

}
```

and use conditional rendering to render it :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      hide1: false,
      hide2: true
    }

  }
})
```

```css
.spacer {
  width: 38px;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.24/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs12>
        <v-layout style="background:#eb596e" fill-height>
          <v-flex shrink v-for="i in 5">
            <v-layout style="background:#51c2d5">
              <v-flex>
                <v-card @click="hide1=!hide1" color="#ffe227" style="height:200px;width:200px" /> {{hide1}}</v-flex>
              <v-flex>

                <div v-if="hide1" class="spacer"></div>
                <v-tooltip top v-else>
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-btn
                      fab
                      v-on="on"
                      style="width:22px;height:20px"
                          v-show="!hide1" 
                    >
                      <v-icon color="primary" size="17px">
                        more_vert
                      </v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                  </template>
                  <span>
                  {{'hello'}}
                  </span>
                </v-tooltip>

              </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```